# linq union of two lists

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object model that contains a list of longs. I want to get the combined list of longs of two different instances. When I write this:

```
var MyCombinedList = TheObject1.ListOfLongs.Union(TheObject2.ListOfLongs);
```

I get an empty list. Note that sometimes `TheObject2` can have an empty list.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Unless your both lists are empty `Union` will not return an empty list.

Comment: @L.B: you're right, I just caught a glitch. What's the difference between Union and Concat and when to use which?

Comment: Frenchie, `Union` eliminates duplicates. `Concat` just appends

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use **[Concat()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx)** this will concatenates two sequences. So try this instead :

```
var MyCombinedList = TheObject1.ListOfLongs.Concat(TheObject2.ListOfLongs);
```

Good Luck !!

Comment: ok, thanks for the answer. What's the difference between Union and Concat and when to use which?

Comment: Actually Concat is behaves as like UnionAll in SQL

Answer (score 10):

how about using `Concat`

```
var list = TheObject1.ListOfLongs.Concat(TheObject2.ListOfLongs).ToList();
```

or

```
var list = TheObject1.ListOfLongs.Union(TheObject2.ListOfLongs).ToList();
```

Comment: ok, thanks for the answer, upvoted. What's the difference between Union and Concat and when to use which?

Comment: @frenchie `Union` removes duplicates. `Concat` does not.